# How do I assign a random seed to the dplyr sample_n function?

Tags: r, dplyr, random-seed, reproducible-research

This is the "sample_n" from dplyr in R.
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample.html

For reproducibility, I should place a seed so that someone else can get my exact  results.

Is there a built-in way to set the seed for "sample_n"?
Is this something that I do in the environment and "sample_n" responds to it?

These are not built-into the "sample_n" function.

- There is the environment "set.seed" function [[1]](https://irudnyts.github.io//setting-a-seed-in-r-when-using-parallel-simulation/)
- There is a library 'withr' that creates a seed-containing wrapper for code [[2]](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/withr/withr.pdf)

.

Comment: There is nothing special about `sample_n`. You have to follow the same steps that you follow for other examples for reproducibility.. `set.seed(any_number);sample_n(mtcars, 1)` would always give the same result. Did you try that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dplyr::sample_n` [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample.html)  tells that :

> This is a wrapper around sample.int() to make it easy to select random rows from a table. It currently only works for local tbls.

so behind `sample_n`, `sample.int` is called, which means that the standard Random Number Generator is used, and that you can use [`set.seed`](http://rfunction.com/archives/62) for reproducibility.

Comment: Maybe add to the answer that `set.seed(123)` needs to be called *each time* before `sample_n` is performed.

Answer (score 4):

Does this example help? In it, I am using `set.seed` and the `mtcars` dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- mtcars
sample_n(x, 10)

sample_n(x, 10) #without set.seed()

set.seed(1)
x <- mtcars
sample_n(x, 10)
```